# How to convert Enum in yaml configuration to a class for parsing purpose (See details for more information)?

Tags: java, enums, yaml, dropwizard

I have an Enum that looks something like this:

```
public Enum Test {

    val1("firstValue", "secondValue"), val2("firstValue2", "secondValue2");

    private String val1;
    private String val2;

    private Test(String val1, String val2) {
        this.val1 = val1;
        this.val2 = val2;
    }
}
```

And, I have a configuration YAML file that looks something like this:

```
conf:
  val1: 1.0
  val2: 2.0
```

For the above config, I have a class defined that parses this YAML so it looks something like this:

```
public class Config {
    Map<Test, String> conf;
}
```

Now, I want to convert this Test enum to class.
So, now my enum would look something like this:

```
public class Test {

    private String val1;
    private String val2;

    public Test(String val1, String val2) {
        this.val1 = val1;
        this.val2 = val2;
    }
}
```

But now the problem is that my app gives an error that it cannot parse the config since it expects **Test** but **String** was provided

Is there a way I can fix this without changing the **Map** in **Config** class from **Map<Test, String>** to **Map<String, String>**?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the YAML structure the only thing you have to do is use `Test` instead of `Map<Test, String>` as follows:

```java
public class Config {
    Test conf;
}
```

This of course assumes your second `Test` class and not the `Test` as an `Enum`.